# MySql, can anyone suggest how to improve my query / index?

Tags: sql, mysql, indexing, query-optimization

Can anyone suggest how I can improve my query, its used for a site map and theres 80000 pages, hence the limit.

Heres my query

```
SELECT PageName
FROM pads
WHERE RemoveMeDate = '2001-01-01 00:00:00'
ORDER BY PadID DESC
LIMIT 20000 , 30000
```

Heres my EXPLAIN

[image]

Heres the indexes I have already

[image]

Comment: What should be the goal of the desired improvement?

Comment: To make it quicker that 1.9 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **not** using any indexes.
How many rows are there in the table overall?

I notice that you are looking for 10k rows out of about 48k rows matching on just RemoveMeDate - the table must be large or you must be selecting a large proportion of the table.

```
SELECT PageName
FROM pads USE INDEX()
WHERE RemoveMeDate = '2001-01-01 00:00:00'
ORDER BY PadID DESC
LIMIT 20000 , 30000
```

Not using any indexes forces it to just scan the table.
Now if that doesn't help and is slower, try to make a specific index that orders DESC, e.g. try one of the two below

```
CREATE INDEX IX_pads_rmd_iddesc ON pads (RemoveMeDate, PadID DESC, PageName)
CREATE INDEX IX_pads_rmd_iddesc ON pads (RemoveMeDate, PadID DESC)
```

In conjunction with FORCE INDEX in case it doesn't get selected automatically

```
SELECT PageName
FROM pads USE INDEX(IX_pads_rmd_iddesc)
WHERE RemoveMeDate = '2001-01-01 00:00:00'
ORDER BY PadID DESC
LIMIT 20000 , 30000
```

Note that even though the indexes re created "PadID DESC", it is ignored by MySQL. One can hope that one day when it gets implemented it will fall into place.

> An index_col_name specification can
>   end with ASC or DESC. These keywords
>   are permitted for future extensions
>   for specifying ascending or descending
>   index value storage. Currently, they
>   are parsed but ignored; index values
>   are always stored in ascending order.

Comment: I don't know why but I get better results on my test server which is a much slower machine, it times out on the live server.

Comment: do you think it could be volume related? 10k bookmark lookups (from index key to data page to get PageName) is not trivial

Comment: Yes I think so, I think I need to rethink my sitemaps.

Answer (score 2):

Optimal index for this query would probably be a combination index on columns `RemoveMeDate`, `PadID`, and `PageName`.

Comment: I've just added that index but theres no improvement, it does seem to use it though, in explain its now in the keys column. Any further suggestions please ?

Comment: Retrieving (up to) 30000 rows in 1.9 seconds isn't necessarily that bad from performance viewpoint. Are you sure the problem is not in the network or somewhere on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

you should look into "force index" or "use index" if correct indexes are not being automatically selected.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/index-hints.html

Comment: I've added the index `RemoveMeDate, PadID, and PageName` (suggested by Tommi above) and added  `FROM pads USE INDEX (remmeda_padid_pagename)` but theres no improvement

Comment: Force index doesn't help either